# Javascript Countdown Timer Not Pulling Current Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, countdowntimer

I've inherited a React project where a jQuery countdown timer is used to hide/display a button. If there is time left on the clock, the button below is unclickable and greyed out, else there is no time left on the clock the button is meant to be clickable and the countdown timer should then be hidden.

The timer counts down, but it is not pulling the correct date to count down to, so it won't expire for another 261 days. I've tried setting the date in the past so that the timer expires and no longer displays, thereby allowing the button to be clickable but that's not working.

I deployed this site as a static build at https://scarebearsnft.com, does that have something to do with it? That it can't get the current date and time from the system?

Handletimer.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';

export const HandleTimer = () => {
    var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 30, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();

    var x = setInterval(function() {
    
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    // If time is left, timer will be displayed and button will be disabled
    if (distance >0) {    
        $(".time").show();
  
        $("#daysTimer").html(days);
        $("#hoursTimer").html(hours);
        $("#minutesTimer").html(minutes);
        $("#secondsTimer").html(seconds);
        
        
        $("#mintBtn").prop('disabled',true) 
        $("#selectBtn").attr('disabled',true) 
        $("#mintBtn").css({'background-color':'gray'})
        $(".mintBtn").hover(function(){
            $(this).css('color','white')
        })
        $("#selectBtn").css({'background-color':'gray'})
      
    }

    // If time has finished, timer will hide and button will be enabled
    else{
        clearInterval(x);
        $(".time").hide();

        $(".mintBtn").mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css("background-color","white");
            $(this).css("color","#850101");
        }).mouseout(function() {
            $(this).css("background-color","#850101");
            $(this).css("color","white");
        }); 
    }
    },1000);
}
```

Topsection.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { connect } from "../redux/blockchain/blockchainActions";
import { fetchData } from "../redux/data/dataActions";
import { counter } from "../hooks/counter";
import Background from '../images/cover.jpeg';


const TopSection = () => {
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = React.useState(counter());
  const [mintvalue, setMintvalue] = React.useState(0);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const blockchain = useSelector((state) => state.blockchain);
  const data = useSelector((state) => state.data);
  const [costOfNFT, setCost] = useState(0.005);
  
  const [claimingNft, setClaimingNft] = useState(false);

  const claimNFTs = (_amount) => {
    if (_amount <= 0) {
      alert("Enter some amount to mint your Scare Bears")
      return;
    }
    else if (_amount > 20){
      alert(`You cannot mint more than ${_amount} Scare Bears at a time`)
      return;
    }
    setClaimingNft(true);
    blockchain.smartContract.methods
      .mint(_amount)
      .send({
        to: "HIDDEN",
        from: blockchain.account,
        value: blockchain.web3.utils.toWei((22 * _amount).toString(), "ether"),
      })
      .once("error", (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        alert(err['message'])
        setClaimingNft(false);
      })
      .then((receipt) => {
        alert("You now own a Scare Bears. go visit Opensea.io to view it.")
        setClaimingNft(false);
        dispatch(fetchData(blockchain.account));
      });
  };
  const getData = () => {
    if (blockchain.account !== "" && blockchain.smartContract !== null) {
      dispatch(fetchData(blockchain.account));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [blockchain.account]);


  React.useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      setTimeLeft(counter());
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(id);
    };
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div
        class="main d-flex align-items-md-center py-5 py-sm-0"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgb(0, 0, 0)), url(${Background})`,
          //backgroundImage: `url(/images/Header.gif)`,
          backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
          backgroundSize: "cover",
        }}
      >
        <div className="main-section">

          <div class="row d-flex align-items-center" style={{
            marginTop: '43px'
            , justifyContent: 'center', paddingBottom: '75px'
          }}>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-center ">
              <div class="col-12 d-flex flex-column">
                {Object.keys(timeLeft).length > 0 && (
                  <div class="row text-center justify-content-around time">
                    <div class="col-2 ">
                      <h3 id="daysTimer">{timeLeft.days}</h3>
                      <h4>Days</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                      <h3 id="hoursTimer">{timeLeft.hours}</h3>
                      <h4>Hrs</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                      <h3 id="minutesTimer">{timeLeft.minutes}</h3>
                      <h4>Min</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                      <h3 id="secondsTimer">{timeLeft.seconds}</h3>
                      <h4>Sec</h4>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )}
                {blockchain.account === "" ||
                        blockchain.smartContract === null ? (
                <div className="row mint" style={{
                  marginLeft: '0px', marginRight: '0px'
                  , justifyContent: 'center'
                }}>
                
                  <div className="col-12">
                    <div class="row d-flex align-items-stretch mint-box-title"
                      style={{ borderColor: 'blanchedalmond', marginLeft: '0px', marginRight: '0px' }}>
                      <p class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        0/4444
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch"
                      style={{ borderColor: 'blanchedalmond', marginLeft: '0px', marginRight: '0px' }}>
                      <h2 class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        ScareBears cost 22 MATIC
                      </h2>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-12">
                    <div class="row right d-flex align-items-stretch"
                      style={{ borderColor: 'blanchedalmond', marginLeft: '0px', marginRight: '0px' }}>
                      <p class="col-md-12 text-center" style={{ fontSize: '12px' }}>
                        CONNECT TO THE POLYGON NETWORK
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-6" style={{ marginLeft: '25%' }}>
                    <button
                      class={"col-12 py-3  mintBtn"}
                      className={`col-12 py-2  mintBtn ${Object.keys(timeLeft).length > 0
                        ? "mint-btn-before"
                        : "mint-btn-after"
                        }`}
                      id="mintBtn"
                      disabled={Object.keys(timeLeft).length > 0}
                      onClick={(e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        dispatch(connect());
                        getData();
                      }}
                    >
                      {!Object.keys(timeLeft).length > 0 ? "CONNECT" : "CONNECT"}
                    </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                  
                </div>
                ):(
                  
                  <div className="col-12" >
                    <div class="row d-flex align-items-stretch mint-box-title"
                      style={{ borderColor: 'blanchedalmond', marginLeft: '1px', marginRight: '0px' }}>
                      <p class="col-md-12 text-center">
                      {data.totalSupply}/4444
                      </p>
                    </div>
                 

                    <div className="col-8"  style={{ marginLeft: '16%' }}>
                      <div className="number">
                        <span className="minus" onClick={() => setMintvalue((mintvalue > 0) ? mintvalue - 1 : mintvalue)}>-</span>
                        <input type="number" min="0" max="20" className="number-mint" value={mintvalue} />
                        <span className="plus" onClick={() => setMintvalue((mintvalue < 20) ? mintvalue + 1 : mintvalue)}>+</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-8" style={{ marginLeft: '15%' }}>
                    <button
                      class={"col-12 py-3  mintBtn"}
                      className={`col-12 py-2  mintBtn ${Object.keys(timeLeft).length > 0
                        ? "mint-btn-before"
                        : "mint-btn-after"
                        }`}
                      id="mintBtn"
                      disabled={Object.keys(timeLeft).length > 0}
                      onClick={(e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        claimNFTs(parseInt(mintvalue));
                        getData();
                      }}
                    >
                      {!Object.keys(timeLeft).length > 0 ? "Mint" : "Minted"}
                    </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12">
                    <div>
                    <div class="row d-flex align-items-stretch mint-box-title"
                      style={{ borderColor: 'blanchedalmond', marginLeft: '0px', marginRight: '0px' }}>
                      <h2 class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        ScareBears cost 22 MATIC
                      </h2>
                    </div>
                  </div>
        
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
                  </div>
                  )}
                
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default TopSection;
```

Comment: "// If time has finished, timer will hide and button will be enabled" No it won't, it actually adds event handlers for those events. AND if `HandleTimer` is called again it adds more.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Are you able to help with pointing out what the correct code should be to get it working?

Comment: Note also `$(".mintBtn").hover(function(){` - this adds another event handler to whatever that identifies each time this function is called and the condition matches.

Comment: SO, since those are all inside the `setInterval` every second new event handlers get added one way or the other. forever

Answer (score 0):

I created a semi-working example by removing the react parts since that is not really part of the question. I would expect you can build from this example.

- remove `stle=` some places and used classes.
- Created an object to hold the values rather than many variables.
- Created functions to call to do what it needed to.
- Created an array of date part names to cycle to update display of.
- Set a "secondsBack" to do a test rather than some days.
- Added a few in-line comments and removed/,moved some code to functions

```js
function getDateFragment(framentType, from) {
  switch (framentType) {
    case 'days':
      return Math.floor(from / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      break;
    case 'hours':
      return Math.floor((from % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      break;
    case 'minutes':
      return Math.floor((from % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      break;
    case 'seconds':
      return Math.floor((from % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
      break;
    default:
      console.log(`Sorry, we are out of ${framentType} time.`);
  }
}
const HandleTimer = () => {
  // this is in the past so "false" will always be the case; make it postive date
  //let countDownDate = new Date("Oct 30, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();

  // hold all our values in one place:
  let timeFragments = {
    interval: 1000, // how long between updates
    daysBack: 2, // go back 2 days on timer
    secondsBack: 16, //for our test
    countDownDate: new Date(),
    now: new Date(),
    distance: 0,
    days: 0,
    hours: 0,
    minutes: 0,
    seconds: 0,
    initTimer: function() {
      this.countDownDate
        //  .setDate(this.countDownDate.getDate() - this.daysBack);
        //for our test seconds not days
        .setSeconds(this.countDownDate.getSeconds() - this.secondsBack);
      this.distance = this.now.getTime() - this.countDownDate.getTime();
    },
    setDistance: function() {
      this.distance = this.distance - this.interval;
    },
    timers: {
      days: $("#daysTimer"),
      hours: $("#hoursTimer"),
      minutes: $("#minutesTimer"),
      seconds: $("#secondsTimer")
    },
    periods: ["days", "hours", "minutes", "seconds"],
    updateTimes: function() {
      this.periods.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
        this[element] = getDateFragment(element, this.distance)
      }, this);
    },
    updateTimer: function() {
      this.timers.days.html(this.days);
      this.timers.hours.html(this.hours);
      this.timers.minutes.html(this.minutes);
      this.timers.seconds.html(this.seconds);
    }
  };
  timeFragments.initTimer();
  timeFragments.setDistance();
  console.log("Date:", timeFragments.countDownDate, timeFragments.distance);
  let x = setInterval(function() {
      timeFragments.setDistance();
      timeFragments.updateTimes();
      // If time is left, timer will be displayed and button will be disabled
      if (timeFragments.distance > 0) { // was false to start with, fixed that
        $(".time").not(":visible").show();
        timeFragments.updateTimer();

        $("#mintMintBtn").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#mintConnectBtn").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#selectBtn").prop('disabled', true);
        /* $("#selectBtn").css({
           'background-color': 'gray'
         })*/

      }
      // If time has finished, timer will hide and button will be enabled
      else {
        console.log("We are here: false");
        clearInterval(x);
        $(".time").hide();
        $("#mintMintBtn").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#mintConnectBtn").prop('disabled', false);
      }
    },
    timeFragments.interval);
  // detect state instead of adding more handlers
  $(".mintBtn").on("mouseenter", function() {
    if ($(this).not(":disabled")) {
      $(this).addClass('over-me').removeClass('not-over-me');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('not-over-me over-me');
    }
  }).on("mouseleave", function() {
    if ($(this).not(":disabled")) {
      $(this).addClass('not-over-me').removeClass('over-me');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('not-over-me over-me');
    }
  });
  $("#mintMintBtn").on("mouseenter", function() {
    if ($(this).is(":disabled")) {
      $(this).css('color', 'white');
    }
  });
};
HandleTimer();
```

```css
.main-section>div.row:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 43px!important;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 75px;
}

.no-x-margins {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.blanche {
  border-color: blanchedalmond;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#selectBtn,
#mintMintBtn:disabled {
  background-color: #808080!important;
}

.over-me {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #850101;
}

.not-over-me {
  background-color: #850101;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main d-flex align-items-md-center py-5 py-sm-0" style='background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgb(0, 0, 0)), url(${Background}) background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size: cover'>
  <div class="main-section">
    <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
      <div class="col col-4 d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex flex-column">
          <div class="row text-center justify-content-around time">
            <div class="col-2">
              <h3 id="daysTimer">0</h3>
              <h4 class="date-header">Days</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <h3 id="hoursTimer">0</h3>
              <h4>Hrs</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <h3 id="minutesTimer">0</h3>
              <h4>Min</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <h3 id="secondsTimer">0</h3>
              <h4>Sec</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mint no-x-margins" style="justify-content: center;">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="row d-flex align-items-stretch mint-box-title blanche">
                <p class="col-md-12 text-center">
                  0/4444
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch blanche">
                <h2 class="col-md-12 text-center">
                  ScareBears cost 22 MATIC
                </h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="row right d-flex align-items-stretch blanche">
                <p class="col-md-12 text-center" style="font-size: 12px;">
                  CONNECT TO THE POLYGON NETWORK
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6" style="margin-left: 25%;">
                <button class="col-12 py-3  mintBtn mint-btn-before" id="mintConnectBtn" onClick="(e) => {e.preventDefault(); dispatch(connect()); getData(); }">
                      CONNECT
                    </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row d-flex align-items-stretch mint-box-title blanche">
              <p class="col-md-12 text-center">
                4/4444
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8" style=" margin-left: 16%;">
              <div class="number">
                <span class="minus" onClick="()=>setMintvalue((mintvalue > 0) ? mintvalue - 1 : mintvalue)">-</span>
                <input type="number" min="0" max="20" class="number-mint" value="3" />
                <span class="plus" onClick="()=>setMintvalue((mintvalue < 20) ? mintvalue + 1 : mintvalue)">+</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8" style="marginLeft: 15%;">
              <button class="col-12 py-3  mintBtn mint-btn-before" id="mintMintBtn" disabled="false" onClick="(e)=> { e.preventDefault();claimNFTs(parseInt(mintvalue)); getData();">Mint</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <div>
                  <div class="row d-flex align-items-stretch mint-box-title blanche">
                    <h2 class="col-md-12 text-center">
                      ScareBears cost 22 MATIC
                    </h2>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```